# Shell Script - SFTP -> If copied, remove?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ftp

Iam trying to copy textfiles with a shellscript over sftp.
I already wrote a script that does the job.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='Servername'
USER='Username'

sftp -b - ${USER}@${HOST} << EOFFTP

get /files/*.txt /tmp/ftpfiles/
rm /files/*.txt

quit

EOFFTP
```

Before I remove all the textfiles on the FTP, I want to make sure, I copied all the files without errors. How can I do this? I use SSH-keys for login.

Task is:
Copy all textfiles over and over but make sure, its not the same ones... (thats why I use remove...)

Maybe I could move them on the FTP? like copy and then move to /files/copied ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, **rsync** is ideal for this:

```
rsync --remove-source-files ${USER}@${HOST}:/files/*.txt /tmp/ftpfiles/
```

Comment: My pleasure.  Back in the days before rsync and ncftp, I wrote many FTP automations in that batch-script style, and I hated every one.